# vcpkg seemingly builds Boost with wrong compiler

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, vcpkg

I am trying to use `vcpkg` to build and use Boost. This might not be the best practice but I modified the triplet `x64-windows` directly and added these

```
set(VCPKG_VISUAL_STUDIO_PATH "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community")
set(VCPKG_PLATFORM_TOOLSET v142)
```

so that it uses the latest Visual Studio I have. Strange thing is, I don't have any other VC++ toolset anyways. This is where things get confusing for me. I do `vcpkg install boost:x64-windows`. It builds fine. Under `${vcpkg_dir}/installed/x64-windows`, I can see that Boost libraries, dlls, includes are just there. When I use this in a CMake project later, with `find_package(Boost)`, I also get `BOOST_FOUND=true`. Boost include dirs, lib dirs etc. are correctly set. Problem is `BOOST_COMPILER` says `v140` and if I go to `${vcpkg_dir}/installed/x64-windows/lib`, I see that boost lib files have names similar to 
`libboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-1_72.lib`. It says `vc140`! If I go to bin folder, I can see that dlls have `vc142` in their name. In my CMake project, I get the variable `BOOST_LIBRARIES` empty.
Of course, in my CMake project, I am using vc142.

So, to me it seems, my CMake project finds the Boost installed with vcpkg just fine. But since it sees incompatible libraries built with vc140, it says `BOOST_LIBRARIES` are empty and I can't link to them. Does anyone have any ideas why `BOOST_COMPILER=v140` even though I set it explicitly to my Visual Studio installation? Again, I don't have any other Visual Studio installation anyways.

Comment: See discussion here at https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/601#issuecomment-276220946